# C++ Pointers and queues

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to make a program that pitches two teams against each other.  Each team has the same number of players.  Lets say team 1 has players A, B, C, D and team 2 has players E, F, G, H.
On round 1, player A goes against player E.  Let's say A won.  Then A goes back to his team (I made it into a queue), so team 1 now has players B, C, D, E.  B goes into loser stack (so I pop it from team 2 and push it to a new queue called loser stack).
Then on round 2, player B goes against player F.  And so on, until only 1 team has players left.

I can't figure out the algorithm for doing this.  I'm not looking for a specific code (or anyone to do my work), I just want some ideas on how people might do this.  I have not learned mapping yet, I'm only allowed pointers and basic functions.  My guess is I have to do some sort of a for loop, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){         //this is the loop for team 1, with 4 players
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {     //this is the for loop for team 2
       //this is the part I need help with:
       //somehow I need to call a player from team 1 from the queue
       //and also call a player from team 2
   }
}
```

Is there a way to call something from a queue?  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: I think you mean "team 1 now has players B, C, D, A" and "E goes into loser stack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fight(Player &p1, Player &p2)
{
    int result = 0; // 1 if p1 wins, 2 if p2 wins
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
std::queue<Player> team1;

std::queue<Player> team2;

std::queue<Player> losers;
while(team1.size() > 0 && team2.size() > 0) {

Player p1 = team1.front();
team1.pop();

PLayer p2 = team2.front();
team2.pop();

int result = fight(p1, p2);

if(result == 1) {
    team1.push(p1);
    losers.push(p2);
} else {
    team2.push(p2);
    losers.push(p1);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes so much sense!

Answer (score 3):

Use two instances of `std::queue` - one for each team. In the beginning, populate them with the players. Then, do a single for loop to iterate over the rouds. In each round, use `std::queue::pop` to get the next player from each team. After the winning player has been chosen, use `push` to put the winning player back to the end of the queue of his team.